# Django getting session 500 error on specific line

Tags: python, django, session, twilio, django-sessions

I'm trying to run the code here: https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/automated-survey-django. The problem I'm stuck on is in the below function, the first time a text is send, there is no session and `request.session.get('answering_question_id')` is false/null. The second text sent from the same number (where I can see there is a new row in the django_session table), returns a 500 error on this line `request.session.get('answering_question_id')`. I see a 500 error is a server error, but I'm stuck on what that could mean for this. I thought the result should just be false/null if `'answering_question_id'` isn't available. Any thoughts?

```
@require_http_methods(["GET", "POST"])
def redirects_twilio_request_to_proper_endpoint(request):
    print("HELLOOOO!")
    answering_question = request.session.get('answering_question_id')
    print("YEPPERS")
    if not answering_question:
        print('1')
        first_survey = Survey.objects.first()
        redirect_url = reverse('survey',
                               kwargs={'survey_id': first_survey.id})
    else:
        print('2')
        question = Question.objects.get(id=answering_question)
        redirect_url = reverse('save_response',
                               kwargs={'survey_id': question.survey.id,
                                       'question_id': question.id})
    return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)
```

Comment: What traceback/error are you getting? (I assume you're getting some error since you mention the line number—if you're not, you can try setting DEBUG to True in your `.env` file.)

Comment: This is an example error I'm getting: [03/Jun/2022 03:34:36]"GET /automated-survey/first-survey/?ToCountry=US&ToState=CA&SmsMessageSid=SM9f799005f09308ae910a7c5af722bf76&NumMedia=0&ToCity=LOS+ANGELES&FromZip=95747&SmsSid=SM9f799005f09308ae910a7c5af722bf76&FromState=CA&SmsStatus=received&FromCity=ROSEVILLE&Body=Pink&FromCountry=US&To=%2B17472454008&ToZip=&NumSegments=1&ReferralNumMedia=0&MessageSid=SM9f799005f09308ae910a7c5af722bf76&AccountSid=ACef9b14863560f9a5b30961d21029d03c&From=%2B19164327401&ApiVersion=2010-04-01 HTTP/1.1" 500 139520

Comment: That looks like an Apache log file error. We want the Python traceback, which will have more useful information. Try changing DEBUG to True in your .env file and opening the page again. If you are using a production WSGI environment (like Apache mod_wsgi or Gunicorn or etc), you should also remove the print statements, as they can interfere.